# error in fread (showProgress is not type integer but type 'logical'. Please report.)

Tags: r, data.table, fread

I have used fread to read data. But the error has arisen:

> showProgress is not type integer but type 'logical'. Please report.

Here is the reproducible script:

```
library(data.table)
x <- "sgsddsfsfsf"
write.csv2(x,"check.csv", row.names=FALSE)
fread("check.csv", stringsAsFactor=FALSE)
```

Example of printscreen:

[image]

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.9.8

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.2
```

Comment: @Tensibai
the version of data.table 1.9.8

Comment: Its working fine for me. Try to start with a new session?

Comment: Working for me too. I'm on 1.9.6

Comment: @ Procrastinatus Maximus
I have opend the new session (new instance of R) - the error is the same :-(

Comment: @ Hack-R
try version 1.9.8

Comment: To be more specific: `data.table 1.9.8` it is working for me with R 3.3.1 on macOS Sierra

Comment: @Procrastinatus Maximus

R- 3.3.2

Comment: @Tensibai
I have added to the major question

Comment: See [this relatively recent change](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/eb9f7efb075aea7584b147e586120cbedc56ee0e#diff-eb1215849c1980935b80b93249783ec5). How have you updated data.table? Did you change options?

Comment: @Tensibai
Sorry I have got lost with all comments above:
> getOption("datatable.showProgress")
[1] TRUE

Comment: @Roland
I have installed data.table from CRAN only. No optiones changed.

Comment: works for me on R 3.3.2 with data.table 1.9.7, can't update easily right now to test latest data table. have you tried options(datatable.showProgress = 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just fixed. Please try again from dev. Thanks for reporting.

> Fixed `fread()` error occurring for a subset of Windows users: `showProgress is not type integer but type logical`, [#1944](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1944) and [#1111](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1111). Our tests cover this usage (it is just default usage), pass on AppVeyor (Windows), win-builder (Windows) and CRAN's Windows so perhaps it only occurs on a specific and different version of Windows to all those. Thanks to @demydd for reporting. Fixed by using strictly `logical` type at R level and `Rboolean` at C level, consistently throughout.

Comment: I have used your advice from [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1944) - see the last message before the closure.I have rebooted my PC. But the issue is still here. So I am going to rollback to older and stable version 1.9.6 (as far as I remember it has worked for me well) and wait for the new update of data.table.

Comment: data.table - 1.9.6 works fine. So I am waiting for the latest update of the package.

Comment: @DimonD. you can install data.table devel from windows binary, no Rtools/compiling needed. You can try `install.packages("https://ci.appveyor.com/api/buildjobs/rhp5e7h6p5ienl67/artifacts/data.table_1.9.9.zip", repos=NULL)` or just  download the zip and use local path to zip. Binaries (R 3.3 win x64) are from appveyor win builder: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/Rdatatable/data-table/build/job/rhp5e7h6p5ienl67/artifacts Please let us know if it fix the issue.

Comment: @DimonD. Yes if you could try that Windows .zip from Jan, would be great to confirm if it is indeed fixed please.  We've never been able to reproduce it before on other Windows machines. You're our only hope. You can always reinstall 1.9.6 again afterwards.

Comment: @Matt Dowle
I am looking forward to update the package in Jan 17.
I will test fread() again by all means because I used this function intensely in my daily routines.

Comment: @jangorecki
I have installed dev version as you wrote.
All is correct this time. At least, I have found no error in this simple example.
Looking forward to update a new production version of the package.

Comment: @Matt Dowle
I have installed the package with [the link]( ci.appveyor.com/project/Rdatatable/data-table/build/job/… Please let us know if it fix the issue) provided by @ jangorecki.
All semms to be ok this time.

Comment: @DimonD. Relief - much thanks. Yes v1.10.0 will be on CRAN soon.

Comment: @Matt Dowle
I have tested the update 1.10.0 - all is correct :-)

Comment: @DimonD.  Excellent. Thanks again and sorry for the hassle.